# Do you know how can I get values from multiple checkboxes (html -> php -> email)?

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I've modified the form from 'freelancer bootstrap template' and I added a few checkboxes. The problem is that when I submit the form I am not getting the values from checkboxes on my email (the rest is fine).

So here are the code lines:

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="row control-group">
  <label id="areas">Areas of Interest:</label>
  <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="areasofinterest[]" value="trade_show_events">trade show & events</label>
  <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="areasofinterest[]" value="websites_optimiaztion">websites & optimization</label>
  <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="areasofinterest[]" value="online_promotions">online promotions</label>
  <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="areasofinterest[]" value="strategic_planning_branding">strategic planning & branding</label>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

$("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        // Prevent spam click and default submit behaviour
        $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        event.preventDefault();

        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var companyname = $("input#companyname").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var areasofinterest = $("input#areasofinterest").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                companyname: companyname,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                areasofinterest: areasofinterest,
                message: message
            },
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
empty($_POST['companyname'])        ||
empty($_POST['email'])      ||
empty($_POST['phone'])      ||
empty($_POST['message'])    ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;}  
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$companyname = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['companyname']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$areasofinterest  = implode(',', $_POST['areasofinterest']);
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'email@domain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the ''        replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact    form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nCompanyName:         $companyname\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone:   $phone\n\nAreasOfInterest:\n$areasofinterest\n\nMessage:\n$message";
  $headers = "From: noreply@domain.com\n"; // This is the email address the   generated message will be from. We recommend using something like   noreply@yourdomain.com.
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
  return true;      
?>
```

I would really appreciate your help :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have any item with id `areasofinterest`

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering so quickly! I added id="areasofinterest" to all the checkboxes and I tried again. No luck :( Did I do sth wrong?

Comment: If you add after this line: `var areasofinterest = $("input#areasofinterest").val();` this code: `alert(areasofinterest)` what does it show?